# For what $n$ is $U_n$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> When can we say a multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$, i.e., $U_n$ is  cyclic?

$$U_n=\{a \in\mathbb  Z_n \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}$$

I searched the internet but did not get a clear idea.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So $U_n$ is the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Write the prime decomposition
$$
n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}.
$$

By the Chinese remainder theorem
$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{\alpha_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{Z}/p_r^{\alpha_r}\mathbb{Z}
$$
so
$$
U_n=U_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}\times\ldots\times U_{p_r^{\alpha_r}}.
$$

For powers of $2$, we have
$$
U_2=\{1\}
$$
and for $k\geq 2$
$$
U_{2^k}=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2^{k-2}\mathbb{Z}.
$$

For odd primes $p$,
$$
U_{p^\alpha}=\mathbb{Z}/\phi(p^\alpha)\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/p^{\alpha-1}(p-1)\mathbb{Z}.
$$

So you see now that $U_n$ is cyclic if and only if
$$
n=2,4,p^\alpha,2p^{\alpha}
$$
where $p$ is an odd prime.

Here is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Comment: Why is it true that $U_{p^\k}=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2^{k-2}\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Julien, why doesn't the even prime work please?

Comment: By equal to symbol $=$ in proof. Did you mean isomorphic?

Comment: Why is it true that $U_{p^\alpha} = \mathbb{Z} / p^{\alpha -1} (p-1) \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: UPD nevermind, I found the answer math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387378/

Comment: What about $n=1$? $(\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is just the trivial group right?

Answer (score 16):

$U_n$ is cyclic iff  $n$ is $2$, $4$, $p^k$, or $2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

The proof follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem for rings and the fact that $C_m \times C_n$ is cyclic iff $(m,n)=1$ (here $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$).

The hard part is proving that $U_p$ is cyclic and this follows from the fact that $\mathbb Z/p$ is a field and that $n = \sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d)$.

Any book on elementary number theory has a proof of this theorem. See for instance  André Weil's *Number theory for beginners*, Leveque's *Fundamentals of Number Theory*, and Bolker's *Elementary Number Theory*.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) "cyclic if and only if $\varphi(n)=\lambda(n)$"  but there's no proof - the proof is elementary but very tricky.