# Determine the units in $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z}, \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ (proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

So, I'm trying to find the units of the following rings:

$$\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z},\, \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z},\, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$

So that means, some elements $a,a'$ in the ring such that $a/a'=1$

By trying different combinations, I am noticing that for $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$

$$7\cdot7 \mod 12 = 1$$ 
$$5\cdot5 \mod 12 =1$$

for all elements that are prime relative to $n$.
That seems to apply to the other two as well.

So my questions are:

1. For a unit $u$ in $R$, does it have to be that $$u\cdot u \mod n = 1$$? That is what my trials resulted in, but is that correct?
2. How to I prove that the units will all be elements prime relative to $n$?

Comment: The units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ form a group called $U(n)$. It has been discussed here on MSE how to determine the units, see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It does not have to be so. For example, $3\times5\equiv1\pmod{7}$.
2. Use Bezout identity. 
   $$\gcd(a,n)=1\iff\exists_{a,b\in\mathbb{Z}} ax+bn=1$$
   and
   $$ax+bn=1\iff ax\equiv1\pmod{n}$$
   Thus $x$ is an unit by the definition.