# When is $Aut\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)$ cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

When is $Aut\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)$ cyclic?

Where $Aut \left( G \right)$ is the group of "Automorphisms of the group $G$" under composition.

> I know that $Aut\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right) \approx U\left(n\right)$ but I don't know when $U\left(n\right)$ is cyclic.

Comment: When $n=1,2,4,p^k$ or $2p^k$ for an odd prime $p$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, I am supposed to show that $U\left(8\right) \approx U\left(12\right)$ but $8=2^3$ Hence $ U\left(8\right)$ is cyclic but $U\left(12\right)$ is not cyclic because $12$ is not of the form you mentioned.

Comment: $U(8)$ is also not of the form I mentioned, so that is not cyclic either.