# Condition that $U_n$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I am a graduate student of Mathematics. I have a course on number theory. Our professor told us a result that $U_n$ is cyclic iff $n=1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$ for $p$ odd prime. But I cannot find any easy proof of the result. This question is answered in stack exchange but the answer is without any explanation: [For what $n$ is $U_n$ cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic)

The answer says $U_{2^k}=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}$ for $k\geq 2$ and $U_{p^k}=\mathbb Z_{\phi(p^k)}$ which are beyond my understanding due to lack of explanation.

Can someone help me by providing a complete easy proof of this result using algebra?

Comment: Maybe the book by I.M. Vinogradov, Elements of number theory, chapter VI will help you.

Comment: Every intro Number Theory text ever written covers this theorem. Get thee to a library! (But, no, there isn't an "easy" proof. It's not a trivial result. But as you are a math grad student, it won't be beyond you.)

Comment: https://youtu.be/a_BiEDdJrR0

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write out a detailed proof of a textbook result, but here are the essentials.

For $p=2$ check that $5 = 1+4$ has (multiplicative) order $2^{k-2}$ with
$5^{2^{k-3}} \equiv 1+2^{k-1} \not\equiv -1 \bmod 2^k$, so $U(2^k) = \langle 5 \rangle \times \langle -1 \rangle \cong C_2 \times C_{2^{k-2}}$ for $k \ge 3$.

For $p$ odd, check that $1+p$ has order $p^{k-1}$. Choose $a$ such that $a$ has order $p-1$ mod $p$. Then the order of $a$ mod $p^k$ is $(p-1)p^t$ for some $t$, so $a^{p^t}$ has order $p-1$ and $U(p^k) = \langle 1+p \rangle \times \langle a^{p^t} \rangle \cong C_{p^{k-1}(p-1)} = C_{\phi(p^k)}$.