# Let $C_n$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Find all automorphisms of $C_n$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $C_n$ be a cyclic group of order $n$,
I want to find all isomorphism from $C_n$ to $C_n$.

If $f: C_n\rightarrow C_n$ is an isomorphism, then for all $x\in C_n$, it exists a generator $g$ s.h  $\:f(x)=f(g^m)=f(g)^m,\:m\in \mathbb{N}$

Now because $f(g)\in C_n$, in order to generate the whole group it must be true that $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$
so they can be $\phi(n)$ automorphism.
More specific the automorphism are $f_1(x)=x,\ldots, f_{\phi(n)}(x)=x^{n-1}$

Now I want to show that the set of those automorphisms, form a cyclic group with order $\phi(n)$ and operation the composition.

$f_1(x)=x$ is the identity element and the inverse of $f_i(x)$ is (don't know)

also I don't know how to prove that $\text{Aut}(C_n)$ is cyclic, don't see why some $\langle f^k\rangle$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ generates all the other isomorphisms

Comment: I note that each automorphism is a permutation of the elements of $C_n$.  Is this group of permutations cyclic?  Is there a choice of $m$ such that $g \mapsto g^m$, $g \mapsto g^{2m}$, $g \mapsto g^{3m}$, ... is the group of automorphisms?  I note that not every cyclic group's subgroup of units has a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

Comment: @EricTowers $m=1$? But only primes have primitive roots, I still don't quite follow

Comment: "But only primes have primitive roots".  False.  $2$, $4$, powers of odd primes and twice powers of odd primes have primitive roots.

Comment: @EricTowers oh ok i see, how primitive roots are relative here?. Every comment here is a new riddle. I need to sleep sometime, thanks for trying to help thought.

Comment: It is not true that the automorphism group of a cyclic group is necessarily cyclic. So what you want to prove is not true, which will make it rather difficult to prove.

Comment: A previous question of yours establishes that $\mathrm{Aut}(C_n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$.  However, the latter is rarely cyclic.  When is it cyclic?  See here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic

Comment: Also, that same question answers this one.  There, you saw that the autos were the homomorphisms $f:C_n \to C_n$ where $f(g)=g^m$, where $m$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $n$ (and $g$ is a generator that is fixed *before* the whole argument begins).  That's it:  that's the description of all the automorphisms of $C_n$.